# dual boot on acer chromebook

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, acer, chromebook

i am using an Acer Chromebook. i have switched operating systems to Ubuntu 12.04 but couldn't watch Netflix so someone told me there is a way to dual boot so wen my laptop comes on, i can choose which operating system. i would love that and use Ubuntu 12.04 (or higher) and Chrome OS. I've searched and cant find anything of how to do it. Has someone does this or know where to look? 
thanks

M.

Comment: You shouldn't need to go through the bother of dual boot. http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_watch_Netflix_%28Watch_Instantly%29_in_Linux

Comment: @Sparhawk The thing is, I also need ubuntu for Gimp, I would prefer to use a dual boot.

Comment: No, I mean that you don't need to dual boot into Windows at all. You can watch Netflix on a pure Ubuntu installation. (Also, the other alternative is to use Gimp in Windows, although I'd obviously recommend using Ubuntu over Windows!)

Answer (score 0):

yeah but windows isn't on the chromebook.
i think supposedly you can run the two linux and chromium
on the chromebook not only in dual boot which is one or the other,
but both at the same time.

https://www.google.com/search?q=run+linux+and+chromium+at+same+time+on+chromebook&rlz=1CAACAC_enUS567US568&oq=run+linux+and+chromium+at+same+time+on+chromebook&aqs=chrome..69i57.15364j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

http://www.itworld.com/open-source/402077/how-run-linux-chromebook

:)

Comment: Instead of just posting links, adding more detail about how this can be done would be better.